# Where are Docker .DEB files for Ubuntu Xenial

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

Title basically states it.

According to Docker instructions here:
https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-from-a-package

Go to https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/, choose your Ubuntu version, browse to pool/stable/ and choose amd64, armhf, ppc64el, or s390x. Download the .deb file for the Docker version you want to install.

However, when I go to https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/xenial/, there is not a single .DEB file to be found.

The machine I'm installing this onto does not and will not have network access.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the guideline says, you have to go further into `pool/stable/amd64/`. There you will find bunch of `deb` files of different docker versions.

The exact link, https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/xenial/pool/stable/amd64/

Comment: Thank you very much.

Clicking the various links landed me here:
https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/xenial/stable/binary-amd64/

Which doesn't have any .DEB files.